# O que é preciso para um sistema dar suporte a um locale?

Tags: localização, cross-platform

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que exigirá um *locale* específico para que funcione corretamente. Ou seja, não é só uma questão de interface de usuário, o sistema como um todo pode ficar inutilizável se o *locale* correto não for suportado (trata-se de funções de processamento de texto, que exigem por exemplo que as regras de maiúsculas/minúsculas e de *collation* sigam um padrão fixo). Gostaria de saber o que é necessário para garantir que o ambiente onde esse sistema será executado dê suporte a esse *locale*.

Desculpe se é uma pergunta básica, mas não sei se **todos** os sistemas [modernos] vêm com suporte para **todos** os *locales* ou se isso é algo que precisa ser configurado a nível de sistema operacional ou de aplicação. A título de exemplo, se no meu PC (Windows XP, locale/encoding `Portuguese_Brazil.1252`) eu tentar atribuir o locale para "Turkish", ele aceita normalmente (`Turkish_Turkey.1254`) - ainda que eu nunca tenha explicitamente instalado o suporte para o idioma turco... No entanto, ao tentar reproduzir [um exemplo que usa esse idioma](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx), não tive sucesso:

```python
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Turkish')
'Turkish_Turkey.1254'
>>> u'mail'.upper() == u'MAIL'
True
```

(segundo o post, deveria dar `False`; será que isso está correto?)

*Edição:* fiz o mesmo teste com Java, e o resultado foi como esperado; acho que meu código Python é que está incorreto...

```java
System.out.println("mail".toUpperCase().equals("MAIL")); // true
Locale.setLocale(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
System.out.println("mail".toUpperCase().equals("MAIL")); // false
```

Fiz o mesmo teste em um computador com Windows 7, e no servidor onde hospedo meu site (FreeBSD, usando `tr_TR.UTF-8`) e tive o mesmo resultado. Estranhamente, num computador com Ubuntu 12.04 não consegui atribuir esse locale... o que reforça a hipótese que uma configuração adicional pode ser necessária. (*Edição:* sim, conforme [o comentário do @J. Bruni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5390/o-que-e-preciso-para-um-sistema-dar-suporte-a-um-locale#comment8590_5390), é necessário instalar manualmente o locale no Ubuntu)

Detalhes adicionais:

- Idealmente, gostaria que usuários em locales diferentes pudessem trabalhar com dados uns dos outros, i.e. se eu processo um texto em português e envio para um turco, ele possa reproduzir o meu resultado, e vice-versa. O importante então não é que **um locale fixo** seja usado em todo lugar, mas sim que **o mesmo locale** usado em um processamento possa ser usado por qualquer um que precise **reproduzir o mesmo processamento** (i.e. mesma entrada, mesma saída).

  De todo modo, a pergunta é a mesma: o que eu como desenvolvedor preciso fazer [durante o *deploy*] para garantir que o ambiente onde o sistema será instalado dê suporte apropriado ao(s) locale(s) necessário(s)?
- No princípio, queria fazer isso no *browser*, via JavaScript. A nova classe [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) me parece promissora, desde é claro que os locales desejados sejam suportados. Na ausência disso, me satisfaço com soluções envolvendo plugins e/ou instalação local (independente de plataforma).

Comment: Pela minha experiência com o Ubuntu, o *locale* a ser utilizado precisa ser instalado. Inclusive, com o comando `locale -a` os *locales* já instalados e disponíveis no meu sistema são listados.

Comment: @J.Bruni Valeu! Instalei o locale turco [seguindo essas instruções](http://askubuntu.com/q/76013/68847), agora o resultado no Ubuntu está consistente com os demais.

Comment: Sem linguagem de programação e/ou OS(es), não fica um pouco amplo demais? Creio que dependa muito do framework e/ou lib principal de cada caso. Qt tem o QLocale, a Windows Api tem seus métodos próprios, Harbour tem suporte interno pra alguns locales, etc (tanto para implementar o locale na linguagem, como pra detectar o locale atual do usuário do OS, que pode ter mais de um instalado). Ou você quer que seu sistema instale no OS do cliente o locale nativo daquela plataforma, por exemplo?

Comment: @Bacco Repito: não sei **nada** sobre locales. Isso que você está dizendo (i.e. que depende da linguagem) é novo pra mim...

Comment: @mgibsonbr tem várias possibilidades que me passaram quando li sua pergunta. Uma é você gerenciar as strings do seu aplicativo, outra é a questão das mensagens nativas do framework ou api( ok/cancel/retry), outra é a questão de formatos de datas, monetários etc. E ainda separado destas, tem a questão do seu app detectar qual o locale do user pra cada uma dessas coisas, como configurado no OS. (em outras palavras, locale "enche o saco" na hora de implementar, e é um problema generalizado isso. Tem muito mais gente perdida nisso do que parece, pq o assunto é cheio dos detalhes)..

Comment: @Bacco Está certo, vou ver se eu "estreito" um pouco a pergunta: estou interessado principalmente em regras de *collation*: como exemplifiquei nos "Detalhes adicionais", se eu faço uma operação de *uppercase* no locale pt_BR (`mail` -> `MAIL`) e envio tudo - mesmo programa, mesma entrada - para um turco, se ele tentar reproduzir meu processamento ele vai ter um resultado diferente (`MAİL`). Eu gostaria, na medida do possível, que ele pudesse executar o meu código no locale pt_BR - de preferência sem ter que instalar nada no SO.

Comment: A plataforma não importa muito: o ideal - JS no browser - parece ser inviável, de modo que alguma instalação local será necessária. Como esse é praticamente o único requisito pra instalação local (todo o resto é viável sem isso), então estou aberto a praticamente toda possibilidade. De novo, dando preferência a soluções que não exijam mexer no SO.

Comment: Sem mexer no SO parece-me complicado, a não ser que o SO já esteja preparado por defeito com locale's. Tenho também mexido muito com isso e é uma dor de cabeça, se calhar era interessante abrires a pergunta no SOEN e depois passavas uma resposta para cá, isto se alguém te responder em condições ;)
Não quero com isto dizer que não haja entendidos disto a falar PT, mas no EN de certeza que é mais abrangente. Desculpa ai o longo comentário para não dizer praticamente nada lol.

Comment: Ja tentou isso? $ dpkg-reconfigure locales

Comment: @rafaels88 Obrigado pela sugestão, mas no meu caso o uso de `locale-gen` foi o suficiente. Em todo caso, a pergunta tem caráter mais geral - não é específica pro Ubuntu (talvez por isso até esteja muito ampla... vou tentar editá-la mais tarde um pouco pra deixar mais "respondível").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trabalhei na internacionalização e localização de alguns sistemas em Java. Não cheguei a usar idiomas muito diferentes dos ocidentais, como os que têm escrita da direita para a esquerda, mas vou relatar os pontos de atenção que provavelmente são importantes em todo o processo de localização.

## Suporte aos *locales*

Suportar diferentes *locales* irá depender do suporte do Sistema Operacional se a linguagem em questão fizer uso de APIs nativas do sistema, o que provavelmente é o caso do Python e outras linguagens usadas primariamente no ambiente Linux/Unix.

Na plataforma Java, por outro lado, a máquina virtual traz certa independência quanto a isso. A [documentação de *locale* do Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html) informa que os JRE's (Java Runtime Environment) podem conter apenas alguns *locales* dependendo da versão instalada. Porém, o JDK (Java Development Kit) vem com todas as versões internacionais instalados.

O Java suporta o padrão ISO 639, que padroniza os idiomas com abreviações de duas letras, e o padrão ISO 3166, que padroniza os países e grandes regiões com duas ou três letras.

## Definindo o *locale* em Java

Há duas formas de definir o *locale* em Java:

1. **Globalmente**, para toda a JVM com o [`Locale.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29).
2. **Localmente**, utilizando parâmetros para as classes de tratamento de datas, números, arquivos de tradução e qualquer método que dependa da localização.

A não ser para aplicações *desktop*, o método recomendado é sempre o segundo.

Em aplicações web, frameworks que dão suporte à localização e internacionalização armazenam o *locale* no escopo de sessão ou no escopo da requisição. O *locale* pode ser selecionado pelo usuário através de configuração ou pelo desenvolvedor por algum critério específico, por exemplo analisando cabeçalhos HTTP.

## Suporte à internacionalização (I18N) em aplicações Java

A localização em Java é comumente feita através de arquivos `.properties`, pois já existem API's na plataforma que lidam bem com esse formato através de implementações como o  [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html) e praticamente todos os frameworks dão suporte a esse padrão.

É indicado adotar a codificação `UTF-8` em todos os arquivos, fontes, páginas web e de texto.

Há um padrão para a nomeação de arquivos `.properties` que permite a trandução para novos idiomas sem alteração no código.

Exemplo:

```
resources.properties
resources_pt.properties
resources_es_ES.properties
```

Nos exemplos acima, se for usado um *locale* como `new Locale("pt", "BR")`, o Java tentará encontrar o arquivo cujo sufixo do nome seja `_pt_BR`. Não encontrando-o, ele carregará o arquivo `_pt`.

Se for usado um *locale* como `new Locale("en", "US")`, o Java tentará encontrar o arquivo cujo sufixo do nome seja `_en_US` ou `_en`. Não encontrando-os, ele carregará o arquivo `resources.properties`, que é o *default*.

É também possível ainda usar interpolação de parâmetros com a classe [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) para deixar as mensagens mais flexíveis. Por exemplo, se você tiver um arquivo `pt_BR` com a mensagem:

```
mensagem=Página {0} de {1}
```

E outro `en_US`:

```
mensagem=Page {0} of {1}
```

Então basta carregar o arquivo de acordo com o *locale* do usuário e processá-lo conforme o exemplo:

```java
ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources", localeUsuario);
String mensagem = resources.getString("mensagem");
mensagem = new MessageFormat(mensagem, localeUsuario).format(
    new Object[] { paginaInicial, paginaFinal });
```

A classe `MessageFormat` suporta alguns tipos de formatação, por exemplo:

```
mensagem=At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.
```

## Suporte à localização (L10N) em aplicações Java

O *locale* deve então ser usado em todos os trechos que processem informações localizadas. Por exemplo:

- Números: [`NumberFormat.getNumberFormat(locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)
- Datas: [`new SimpleDateFomat(pattern, locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)
- Strings: [`Collator.getInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html), `new MessageFormat(pattern, locale)`

Pode parecer simples, mas é fácil, muito fácil, deixar passar detalhes no vai e vem de informações do *front* para o *back-end*.

Um detalhe muito importante é que o *font-end* deve estar sempre em sincronia com o *back-end* e isso implica em que os componentes visuais como *date pickers* ou *masked inputs* de números devem receber as respectivas formatações.

Nesse ponto, frameworks *component based* como JSF ou Struts ajudam com componentes que suportam localização automaticamente. Por outro lado, frameworks *action based* que estão "desacoplados" do front-end podem se beneficiar de componentes Javascript como os do jQUery UI que suportam máscaras.

## Processamento de texto localizado

A plataforma Java fornece API's específicas para diferentes tarefas.

Para comparação de texto considerando a localização pode-se usar a classe [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html). Existem configurações bem específicas na classe, que valem a pena uma lida na documentação.

A classe [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) fornece uma API para lidar com caracteres Unicode de forma genérica.

Para detectar [letras](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/char.html) e [palavras](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/word.html) em diferentes idiomas é possível usar a API [`BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html).

## Pontos adicionais

Além da linguagem, o banco de dados estar preparado para armazenar e recuperar dados nos idiomas suportados. Isso significa que se houver rotinas (procedures e functions) elas também devem considerar a localização. Nesses casos, é mais fácil deixar o processamento de textos para o sistema de forma que a preocupação fique centralizada em um ponto.

Também deve-se considerar a exibição de dados de diferentes localidades. Por exemplo, quando um usuários no Brasil visualiza uma página com informações geradas por um usuário da China. Infelizmente não há muito o que fazer quando o sistema operacional ou navegador não dão suporte aos caracteres de uma língua. No entanto, deve-se adotar na página web uma fonte com suporte a toda a faixa de caracteres Unicode suportada pelo sistema.

Outro ponto é a questão de busca e indexação. Não trabalho com sistemas de busca, mas dada as particularidades que os diferentes idiomas possuem, é visível que implementar uma busca genérica que funcione em qualquer localidade é muito complicado. Não é impossível, mas o sistema provavelmente irá precisar de implementações específicas, tal como considerar termos comuns que são ignorados, construções e composição de palavras, sinônimos, etc.

## Considerações finais

I18N e L10N são tópicos complexos e, infelizmente, é muito difícil estabelecer regras gerais para qualquer localidade. E isso somente no escopo da plataforma Java.

Existe um [tópico do JavaSE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/index.html) para tratar especialmente sobre o assunto que aborda mais profundamente os tópicos resumidos na resposta.

No geral, ao processar os dados devidamente com algum API com suporte à localização, é possível receber e exibir informações de e para qualquer *locale*, de acordo com as regras de cada um.

Um artigo prático (em Inglês) que fala sobre isso é: [*Java Internationalization and Localization*](http://joyofgroovy.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/java-internationalization-and.html).

Comment: "Suportar diferentes locales irá depender do suporte do Sistema Operacional *se a linguagem em questão fizer uso de APIs nativas do sistema*..." "Na plataforma Java, por outro lado, *a máquina virtual traz certa independência quanto a isso*." É só **isso** que eu precisava saber, obrigado! Apesar de toda minha contextualização - e de frisar repetidas vezes que sou 100% n00b no assunto - as pessoas parecem estar lendo demais nas entrelinhas da pergunta... Essas informações - em particular as referências apresentadas - serão muito úteis pra me ajudar a definir minha estratégia.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Confesso que também li muito nas entrelinhas. O problema é que conhecemos sua reputação. Quando você diz que "não sabe muito" sobre algo, imaginamos que, ao invés de estar no 99º percentil do que mais sabem sobre o assunto, está apenas no 98º. :D

Answer (score 1):

A questão é vaga, no sentido de abranger desde problemas de instalação no UBUNTU até questão de se implantar ou não um sistema em Web... E ter sido marcada apenas com as tags #localização e #cros-plataform. A resposta não precisa ser vaga, como já demonstrou o @utliz, mas me dou a liberdade de focar no que me parecem ser "prioridades do contexto". Outros podem editar, está em modo Wiki.

### .. Lembretes ...

## UTF-8

É um padrão "[de facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto)" e "[de jure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure)", como já [exposto nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8442/4186). Todas as linguagens (inclusive Javascript) e todas as formas decentes de intercâmbio de dados (ex. JSON e XML) aceitam UTF8, e portanto podem lidar com localidades multiplas.

**Tudo** no sistema precisa rodar **em UTF8**: ao certificar-se disto, terá dado o primeiro e mais importante passo.

Se for banco de dados ou algo que envolva funções de ordenação de texto, em geral ao configurar *charset* (UTF8) também se configura a *[collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation)*, que dá a ordem do *charset*. Aí é configuração de sistema, de framework ou de biblioteca, e precisa averiguar se pode ser configuração dinâmica (algumas bases de dados não permitem mudar, então complica na hora de misturar idiomas na mesma base). Capturar a configuração do servidor (ou mesmo do client) nem sempre é a melhor solução.

## HTML

Trata-se da *lingua franca*, não apenas dos conteúdos da Internet, mas também de intercâmbio de conteúdos ou fragmentos de conteúdo. Ferramentas *Javascript* como o [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) podem ser plenamente localizadas, inclusive para o turco, permitindo edição plena (criação ou alteração de fragmentos de HTML) do idioma desejado.

### Javascript

Apesar de todos traumas que temos com *cross-browser* e até com *locale* do Javascript, é ainda a linguagem com maior potencial de não fazer confusão com línguas (pelo contrário temos até [detectores de lingua como este](http://www.corpuswiki.org/langdetect.html))... Muita gente aposta o Javascript justamente porque pode-se rodar o mesmo código (ex. validador de CPF ou detector de língua) no client (navegador), no server (ex. *Node.js*) e na base de dados (ex. PostgreSQL roda PL com Javascript).

Talvez você tenha problemas com funções nativas de resolução de datas, mas existem bibliotecas Javascript as mais variadas, e todo o restante é multilingual. Alias, jQuery é uma das ferramentas mais usadas para se reformatar interface dinâmica localizada. Se o caso for interpretar texto de diferentes línguas, mais um motivo, o acesso fácil ao DOM é fundamental.

## Template multilingual

Existem princípios bem simples e gerais para se organizar as linguas da interface e mesmo das funcionalidades (ex. filtros e refinamentos linguisticos aplicados ao HTML editado)... [Neste tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/smallest-template-system/wiki/PHP#Multilingual/Multistyle_helper-functions) temos justamente um exemplo de como os templates multilinguais mais simples podem ser implementados.

[Neste outro link](https://code.google.com/p/habemus-papam/wiki/Introduction#Multilingual_Template) temos um exemplo clássico de template multilingual, uma espécie de "locale" do Vaticano, usado desde 1600.

## I18N e L10N

É o jargão da "velha guarda" para os tópicos discutidos na pergunta, *"Multilingual and internationalization services"*: sistemas robustos (ex. Java) e sistemas mais antigos (ex Cobol, C++, etc.), usam esse jargão. Sistemas mais novos podem ficar com a noção mais geral de "locale"... No final é só uma questão de "se encontrar" nos manuais.

No universo UNIX/Linux foi o padrão *POSIX* que fixou as convenções que usamos até hoje.

*L10N*: datas, moedas, etc.  Para jQuery existem iniciativas como o [jquery-localize](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize) e o [globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)... Cada linguagem, cada framework terá o seu.

### Detecção

Deduzir o "locale" de um usuário pode ser uma arte... Saber com exatidão é até simples, mas requer esquemas de autenticação (ex. login e depois session) e um cadastro confiável. As deduções mais comuns são baseadas na hierarquia de usuários e na posição geográfica do *client*:

- hierarquia: se cadastrou como "membro do departamento", por exemplo, o usuário herda os atributos de locale do departamento.
- geolocalização do agente do usuário: celulares e servidores (ex. LAN onde se encontra o *client*) hoje respeitam padrões de geolocalização, que, para efeitos de locale, não precisam ser dados precisos (em geral basta o código do país).

Num formulário o campo mais importante para estabelecer o locale é o `país`, mas em países como Canadá, Holanda, India, etc. o usuário pode ter lá as suas preferências, então o campo `idioma` acaba sendo igualmente importante.

Comment: Sinto muito se a pergunta ficou vaga, tentei contextualizar o mais que pude, mas minha falta de conhecimento no assunto deve ter atrapalhado bastante. Coloquei os exemplos dos SOs (Windows XP/7, Ubuntu e FreeBSD) apenas para comparar o suporte padrão dado pelos mesmos, mas não buscava um SO específico. Da mesma forma, não sabia se o suporte era a nível de linguagem ou de SO (parafraseando a própria pergunta), daí o `cross-platform`, pois eu queria uma explicação em caráter mais geral mesmo. Em suma, estava completamente perdido, mas as respostas aqui - inclusive a sua - me ajudaram bastante.