# PHP echo Problema com caracteres especiais ("ç")

Tags: php, data

Estou a desenvolver um site que faz um display dos nomes dos meses com `strftime`. O html já está com 'charset=UTF-8'. O problema é que no display do nome do mês aparece como na imagem abaixo

[image: c cedilha não reconhecido]

Fiz um pequeno teste a seguir com o nome do mês e funcionou corretamente, por isso suponho que o problema seja na funcão date. O código que utilizei é o seguinte:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' );
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

$uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
echo strftime( '%A, %d de ' .$uppercaseMonth. ' de %Y', strtotime('today'));
echo (" ....Março");
```

Resolvido:

```
echo utf8_encode(strftime( '%A, %d de ' .$uppercaseMonth. ' de %Y', strtotime('today')));
```

Comment: "date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon')" - esse Europa/Lisboa não interfere? não deveria ser algo como America/Sao_Paulo? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.america.php

Comment: Eu sou de Portugal, logo penso que esta seja a maneira correta

Comment: ah! as vezes esqueço que temos usuários que não são brasileiros...

Comment: cara, sempre tive problemas com ISO. Procure sempre iniciar seu aplicativo ja com UTF-8, voce nao tera mais problemas com acentuacao

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Não se usa mais charset ISO, usar UTF-8!

O ISO Latim foi aposentado anos atras, o W3C vem sugerindo uso de UTF8 (ver [RFC-3629](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt)) em todas as recomendações. Da mesma forma, para sites brasileiros, a recomendação [e-PING](http://eping.governoeletronico.gov.br/) é o **padrão charset UTF-8**...
*Padrão de fato*: idem, UTF-8. Se conferir grandes portais brasileiros ou mesmo protugueses, vai ver logo no header HTML que o padrão adotado é UTF8 (ex. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"../>` do código-fonte da [UOL](http://www.uol.com.br/)).

---

A sua instrução `setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8'...)`pode estrar priorizando ISO e ignorando UTF8 — veja [o que diz o manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php), *"se locale for uma matriz ou conter parâmetros adicionais, então cada elemento da matriz é tentado como um local até obter sucesso"*.
Sugiro apenas UTF-8.

Um possível `setlocale`, já votado,  é a dica de https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927727 ,  mas cuidado com confusão-Windows,

```php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');    
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL); // limpa com defaults do sistema... não precisa.
// ERRADO, força Windows setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8'); // acho mais correto.
```

Adaptando para as suas preferências, seria algo como

```php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR', 'Portuguese_Brazil');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
```

---

Eu pessoalmente uso sempre a seguinte configuração:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_BR.UTF8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF8'); 
mb_regex_encoding('UTF8');
```

### Seus scripts PHP... São UTF8?##

Outro problema comum é o seu próprio script de PHP, que precisa estar também em UTF8(!). Confira com algum editor sério e confiável (jamais o NotePad do Windows!), como por exemplo [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ou [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/).

Idem bases de dados, arquivos XML, etc. Precisa estar tudo no mesmo *charset*, e, fácil: basta sempre configurar tudo  com o "padrão universal", que é o UTF8.

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema num servidor que não possuía locale utf8 disponível para ptbr. Acabei tendo que dar um utf8_encode do mês antes de dar a saída.

Comment: Hoje em dia todos os sistemas operacionais sérios (até o Windows!) possuem suporte para UTF-8. RECUSAR, ou ao menos desconfiar de, qualquer coisa que não possua suporte para UTF-8.

Comment: Resposta foda!
Me ajudou muito em uma situação onde precisava ler arquivos de imagens de um diretório e copiar para outro, parabéns!

Answer (score 3):

Entre as tags *<head></head>* insira:

Para html 4.0/4.1 ou xhtml 1.0:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Para html 5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Isso vai definir que os caracteres que o php "encodou" em UTF-8 serão entendidos como UTF-8. O que fará dar certo.

Answer (score 2):

**Opção 1:**

Veja a codificação da sua página php.
São 2 lugares para ver:

- quando num servidor (Ex apache, iis) as páginas são servidas com uma codificação defalut (no caso so apache é utf-8).
- Codificação do arquivo, olhe com qual codificação sua página foi salva (o local dessa informação vai depender do editor/ide)

As duas codificações acima devem ser iguais.

**Opção 1.1 não elegante**

veja se ela está em `UTF-8` ou `ISO-8859-1`, se estive em utf mude para iso , se estive em iso mudo para utf.
Veja qual que funciona.

**Opção 2:**

use a função [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) para converter em entidades html

```
echo htmlentities(" ....Março");
```

Comment: Obgado pela resposta... Como insiro a função 'htmlentities()' (baseado no meu codigo em cima)? Tentei de várias maneiras e não consegui

Comment: Fica assim `echo htmlentities(" ....Março");`

Answer (score 2):

### Solução sem gambiarras:

Este é um problema comum causado quando se utiliza diferentes encodings no projeto.

Para prevenir este problema, o ideal é utilizar **`UTF-8`** como encoding padrão em tudo que fizer parte do seu projeto:

- Em todos os arquivos do seu projeto;
- No seu banco de dados;
- Nos headers enviados para o usuário;
- Se você utiliza alguma IDE como Eclipse, configure o padrão dos arquivos para o novo encoding também.

Com isto, você se certifica de que qualquer texto que vá para o usuário esteja consistente e falando a mesma "língua", prevenindo esse tipo de erros de uma vez por todas.

Answer (score 2):

Para usar o `htmlentities()` no seu caso, faça o seguinte:

```
$uppercaseMonth = htmlentities(ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Vejo que você não definiu a codificação que o php em si vai trabalhar... adicione isso no topo da pagina que deve resolver:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicionando apenas `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8');` ao invés de `setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' );` já corrige o problema.

[image: php output]

Answer (score 0):

Vou dar apenas uma opnião como complemento, visto que os companheiros responderam sabiamente anteriormente.

Eu sempre costumo configurar a opção `default_charset` do **php.ini** como `utf-8`.
Isso evita problemas como ter que ficar configurando codificação diretamente no código.

O que você também pode fazer é usar `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')` no início do documento.

O problema nesse caso é que, se o seu servidor for compartilhado, provavelmente não terá acesso ao **php.ini** e, se estiver desabilitada a função `ini_set`, a solução (pelo lado do PHP) é usar o `header("Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8")` como citado anteriormente.