# Tratando dados Array PDO CRUD

Tags: php, pdo, paginação, crud

**lista-prato.php:**

```
  <?php 
    //inclui as bibliotecas
    require_once('conexao.class.php');
    //faz a canexão 
    $pdo = new Conexao();

    // determina o numero de registros que serão visualisados
    $maximo = 20;
    // armazenamos o valor da pagina atual
    $pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? ($_GET['pagina']) : '1';
    // subtraimos 1, por que os registros sempre começam do 0
    $inicio = $pagina - 1;
    //multiplicamos a quantidade de registros pelo valor da pagina atual
    $inicio = $maximo * $inicio;


    $strCount = $pdo->select("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'id_prato', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'preco' FROM prato");

    $total = 0;
    $pratoId = 0;

if(count($strCount)){
    foreach ($strCount as $row)  {
        // armazeno total de registros da tabela para fazer paginação
        $total = $row["id_prato"];

    }

    $pratoid = $pdo->select("SELECT  id_prato FROM prato");
    $titulo = $pdo->select("SELECT  titulo FROM prato");
    $descricao = $pdo->select("SELECT  descricao FROM prato");
    $preco = $pdo->select("SELECT  preco FROM prato");
    }
echo "<pre><p> Total de pratos cadastrados</p>" . print_r($total, 1) . "<pre>";
?>

        <table class="tabela1">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="coluna1"/>
                <col class="coluna2"/>
                <col class="coluna3"/>
            </colgroup>
            <caption>Pagina&ccedil;&atilde;o com PHP</caption>          
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Prato</th>
                    <th>Descricao</th>
                    <th>Preco</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                //se a tabela nao estiver vazia, percorremos linha por linha pegando os valores
                if(count($strCount)){
                    foreach ($strCount as $res) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "  <td>".print_r($pratoid, 1)."</td>";
                        echo "  <td>".print_r($titulo, 1)."</td>";
                        echo "  <td>".print_r($descricao, 1)."</td>";
                        echo "  <td>".print_r($preco, 1)."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";

                    }
                }
            ?>
```

**RESULTADO:**

```
         Total de pratos cadastrados
    8
                Paginação com PHP          

 Codigo         Prato           Descricao                       Preco

                                     Array
    (
    )
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => xx
                [0] => xx
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => f
                [0] => f
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => adad
                [0] => adad
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => aa
                [0] => aa
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => f
                [0] => f
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => czx
                [0] => czx
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => zc
                [0] => zc
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [titulo] => ddd
                [0] => ddd
            )

    )
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => xx
                [0] => xx
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => f
                [0] => f
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => dasda
                [0] => dasda
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => aa
                [0] => aa
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => f
                [0] => f
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => zxc
                [0] => zxc
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => zxc
                [0] => zxc
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [descricao] => dd
                [0] => dd
            )
```

Como organizo esses dados para imprimir as informações corretas nas tabelas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `print_r()` é uma função para imprimir a estrutura de um array/objeto bom para realizar debbugins, no seu caso não não é necessário usar ele. Para exibir os valores corretamente, faça um foreach e use o nome das chaves correspondetes.

Como as informações são da mesma tabela não é necessário fazer uma consulta para cada coluna.

```
$pratoid = $pdo->select("SELECT  id_prato FROM prato");
$titulo = $pdo->select("SELECT  titulo FROM prato");
$descricao = $pdo->select("SELECT  descricao FROM prato");
$preco = $pdo->select("SELECT  preco FROM prato");
```

O bloco a cima deve ser trocado por esse que faz a mesma coisa porem usando uma consulta.

```
$pratos = $pdo->select("SELECT  id_prato, titulo, descricao, preco FROM prato");

//Caso queira exibir todos os campos troque os nomes por asterisco
//$pratos = $pdo->select("SELECT * FROM prato");
```

Para exibir as informações dos pratos basta chamar as chaves corretas seus nomes são definidos na consulta sql.

```
if(count($strCount)){
   foreach ($pratos as $res) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['id_prato'] ."</td>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['titulo'] ."</td>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['descricao'] ."</td>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['preco'] ."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Deste modo não é impresso nada na tela.

Comment: @manzetti.denis ele não imprime nem as celulas vazias da tabela?

Comment: não. fiz umas alterações: 
`if($pratos>0){
   foreach ($pratos as $res) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['id_prato'] ."</td>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['titulo'] ."</td>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['descricao'] ."</td>";
      echo "  <td>". $res['preco'] ."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }

}   var_dump($pratos)` pelo que eu entendi, não tem valor nenhum salvo em `$pratos`. O programa imprime: **array (size=0)
  empty**

Comment: @manzetti.denis A definição de `$pratos` está igual a resposta?

Comment: ele só imprime o `$total`, que é o número de registros da coluna `id_prato`

Comment: Código atualizado: http://pastebin.com/TxaKH1ML <-

Comment: Mude seu if de `if($pratos > 0)` para `if(count($pratos) > 0)`. @manzetti.denis

Comment: Consegui, usei `$pratos = $pdo->select("SELECT * FROM prato");` e funcionou.

Comment: Então o nome de alguma coluna foi escrito errado na consulta para não ter retornado nada. @manzetti.denis

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, não está imprimindo caracteres como **"ç"**. 
No banco atribui as colunas como **utf8-bin**. tem alguma coisa a ver?

Comment: @manzetti de uma olhada [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8429/91) talvez o problema seja a codificação do arquivo ou a saída do html