# Problema com acentuação em exportação de arquivo CSV

Tags: php

Fiz uma leitura de um arquivo CSV da seguinte forma:

```
$delimitador = ';';
$cerca = '"';

// Abrir arquivo para leitura
$f = fopen($_FILES['uploadChange']['tmp_name'], 'r');
if ($f) {

    // Ler cabecalho do arquivo
    $cabecalho = fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);

    // Enquanto nao terminar o arquivo
    while (!feof($f)) {

        // Ler uma linha do arquivo
        $linha = fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
        if (!$linha) {
            continue;
        }

        // Montar registro com valores indexados pelo cabecalho
        $registro = array_combine($cabecalho, $linha);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($registro);
        echo "</pre>";

    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

Ao ler e ir para o print_r() o meu retorno está OK,porém, quando há acentuações nas linhas ele não exibe corretamente. Como eu poderia ajustar?

Exemplo de retorno:

```
Array
(
    [Nome] => Andr� Baill
    [Idade] => 29
    [telefone] => (99) 9 9999-999-9999
    [email] => emaildeexemplo@exemplo.com
)
```

Comment: Acho que o teu problema tem a haver com isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8429/php-echo-problema-com-caracteres-especiais-%C3%A7

Comment: Se fizer isso acontece o que ? `$registro = array_combine($cabecalho, utf8_decode($linha));`

Comment: @Gumball se eu fizer da forma que disse, dá erro:  utf8_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Entendi. Então, é que precisa ser string mesmo. Veja a codificação que foi salvo o arquivo, nas opções do Excel.

Comment: Você vai ter que percorrer a variável `$registro` com um `for` ou `foreach`. Guardar em outro `array` os dados usando `utf8_decode`.

Answer (score 2):

André, parece que seu cenário é o seguinte:

- O arquivo php está salvo em UTF8.
- O arquivo csv que está sendo aberto está em ansi/iso.

Como a sua saída será em UTF8 pelo fato do seu arquivo php estar em utf8, você tem as seguintes opções:

1) Passar a salvar em utf8 os arquivos csv.

2) Converter o arquivo csv para utf8 e ressalvá-lo antes de importar.

3) Converter os valores pontualmente. Se for fazer desse jeito, pode ser da seguinte forma:

Adicionar:

```
    foreach($linha as $key => $value)
    {
        $linha[$key] = utf8_encode($value);
    }
```

Após o trecho:

```
    if (!$linha) {
        continue;
    }
```

Nota: Se converter algo que já está em utf8 para utf8 vai dar problema. Caso vc não tenha certeza que o arquivo virá em ansi/iso não poderá sair convertendo diretamente.

Uso a seguinte função quando quero verificar se uma string está em utf8:

```
function is_utf8($str) 
{
    $c=0; $b=0;
    $bits=0;
    $len=strlen($str);
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        $c=ord($str[$i]);
        if($c > 128){
            if(($c >= 254)) return false;
            elseif($c >= 252) $bits=6;
            elseif($c >= 248) $bits=5;
            elseif($c >= 240) $bits=4;
            elseif($c >= 224) $bits=3;
            elseif($c >= 192) $bits=2;
            else return false;
            if(($i+$bits) > $len) return false;
            while($bits > 1){
                $i++;
                $b=ord($str[$i]);
                if($b < 128 || $b > 191) return false;
                $bits--;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Seu código adaptado:

```
<?php

function is_utf8($str) 
{
    $c=0; $b=0;
    $bits=0;
    $len=strlen($str);
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        $c=ord($str[$i]);
        if($c > 128){
            if(($c >= 254)) return false;
            elseif($c >= 252) $bits=6;
            elseif($c >= 248) $bits=5;
            elseif($c >= 240) $bits=4;
            elseif($c >= 224) $bits=3;
            elseif($c >= 192) $bits=2;
            else return false;
            if(($i+$bits) > $len) return false;
            while($bits > 1){
                $i++;
                $b=ord($str[$i]);
                if($b < 128 || $b > 191) return false;
                $bits--;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
} 


$delimitador = ';';
$cerca = '"';

// Abrir arquivo para leitura
$f = fopen('arquivo.csv', 'r');
if ($f) {

    // Ler cabecalho do arquivo
    $cabecalho = fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);

    // Enquanto nao terminar o arquivo
    while (!feof($f)) {

        // Ler uma linha do arquivo
        $linha = fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimitador, $cerca);
        if (!$linha) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach($linha as $key => $value)
        {
            if(!is_utf8($value))
            {
                $linha[$key] = utf8_encode($value);
            }
        }

        // Montar registro com valores indexados pelo cabecalho
        $registro = array_combine($cabecalho, $linha);

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($registro);
        echo "</pre>";

    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

Arquivo arquivo.csv utilizado para testar:

```
NOME;EMAIL
"André Baill";"srandrebaill@gmail.com"
"João";"joãozito@mail.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi de forma simples
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "iso-8859-15")