# POST php com charset utf-8

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres

Bom dia,
após procurar extensivamente por soluções para meu problema, tentando várias soluções que foram sugeridas em outra perguntas, como nesta por exemplo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653119/what-does-phps-mb-internal-encoding-actually-do

Estou buscando informações de um POST php de uma consulta ao banco de dados Oracle, porém o output destas informações, pode conter caracteres especias: no banco de dados está salvo como "João" no post sai "Jo?o".

Gostaria da dica dos amigos para uma configuração (ideal que seja global php.ini) onde pudesse configurar o charset do output php. Algumas configurações que já fiz:

PHP.ini

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
internal_encoding = 'utf-8'
output_encoding = 'utf-8'
```

Index.php

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
    <body>
     <?php
      var_dump($result1);
     ?>
```

...["NOME"]=> string(4) "Jo?o" ...

Sendo que no banco de dados está salvo corretamente:

[image: banco]

Conexão com o banco:

```
$host="10.0.0.2";
$service="//10.0.0.2:1521/orcl";
$conn= new \PDO("oci:host=$host;dbname=$service","USER","senha");
```

Se dou o comando abaixo para verificar o encoding da string, recebo 'ASCII'

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($result1['NOME']);
```

Também já tentei usar a function utf8_encode(); mas nada muda.. :(

Se escrevo outros textos no index.php que contenham caracteres especiais eles são exibidos normalmente, por isso, acredito não ser uma alguma config no arquivo a nível de editor ou meta tag.

Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Tenho quase a certeza que tem a haver com isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8429/php-echo-problema-com-caracteres-especiais-%C3%A7

Comment: @Miguel Tentei fazer o sugerido no post: setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_BR.UTF8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF8'); 
mb_regex_encoding('UTF8'); mas aí recebo o erro no console: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined f
unction mb_internal_encoding()

Comment: Poderia adicionar a sua conexão com o banco na pergunta? Já deu uma olhada neste tópico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%C3%BAvida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8

Comment: Tem como ver por onde foi gravado? Terminais ou arquivos de programas que podem ter esse encoding?

Comment: @AllanAndrade adicionei a pergunta.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino fiz o insert do dado no banco via INSERT normal.

Comment: @Gabrielhn, tenta isso na sua string de conexão ==>                      $conn= new \PDO("oci:host=$host;dbname=$service;charset=utf8","USER","senha");

Comment: Na minha conexão eu adiciono essa linha putenv("NLS_LANG=PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.AL32UTF8") or die("Falha ao inserir a variavel de ambiente");

Comment: Talvez ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: Existe tb o encode do arquivo. O notepad++ é o editor mais fácil de visualizar encode do arquivo e setar UTF8 certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código de conexão não foi informado o `charset` da conexão.

Defina o charset da conexão adicionando `;charset=utf8` no final da string de conexão, exemplo:

```
$conn= new \PDO("oci:host=$host;dbname=$service;charset=utf8","USER","s‌​enha");
```

Conferir o charset das tabelas e campos do seu banco de dados:

> Todos estão com UTF-8?

Setar header no PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Setar header no HTML (você já fez):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Alan, tentei fazer desta forma, mas aí ao carregar a página, recebo o seguinte erro: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCINlsCharSetNameToId: unknown character set name (ext\pdo_oci\o
ci_driver.c:610)' in C:\www\Intranet\perfil.php:12

Ao verificar esse link, vi que UTF8 seria suportado sim. Aí não entendi mais nada: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/applocaledata.htm#i635016

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo algumas maneiras, para caso um não funcione o outro tente rsrs

- Se for só para o caso **João** para **Jo?o** pode tentar assim na hora de escrever:

> 

```
echo utf8_decode($nome);
```

- A outra maneira que utilizo é assim quando vem do banco:

> 

```
echo mb_strtoupper($nome,'UTF8');
```

- Outra é quando eu conecto com o banco:

> 

```
class ConnectionFactory{
    private $ora_user = "login"; 
    private $ora_senha = "senha"; 
    private $ora_bd = "(DESCRIPTION=
                        (ADDRESS_LIST=
                        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip-do-server)(PORT=1521))
                        )
                        (CONNECT_DATA=
                        (SERVICE_NAME=servico)
                        )
                        )"; 
    public  function  getConnection(){
            putenv("NLS_LANG=PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.AL32UTF8") or die("Falha ao inserir a variavel de ambiente");
            $ora_conexao = oci_connect($this->ora_user, $this->ora_senha, $this->ora_bd);
        return $ora_conexao;

    }

    public function closeConnection($connection){
        $ora_conexao = oci_close($connection);

    }


}
```

- Ou como o colega Allan Andrade falou, utilizando o header:

> 

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comigo funcionou. Espero que ajude